# Outlook 2007: How to programmatically select signature based on email recipient (To: CC: BCC:, etc)

Tags: ms-office, outlook-2007, signature

The method does not concern me. Whether it is a macro, or somehow automatically fires as the email is sent.
I want to know if there is a way for outlook to automatically assign a signature based on the recipient.

- Must work with Outlook 2007. If alternate methods exist, they can be added, referencing which version it works on. A lot of my macros had to be rewritten for 2007.

  Method is not important, as long as it doesn't involve user interaction other than regular UI usage to send an email.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I want to do something similar...

Answer (score 0):

Based on code from here http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm

You can set it up to be called from Application_ItemSend but that is probably asking for trouble.

```
Sub With_Variable_Signature()
Dim itm As mailItem
Dim StrSignature As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim recip As Recipient

Set itm = ActiveInspector.currentItem

sPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\defaultSig.htm"

For Each recip In itm.Recipients
    Debug.Print recip.name
    If recip.name = "somebody"  And recip.type = olTo Then ' or = olcc or = olbcc
        sPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\customizedSig.htm"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Dir(sPath) <> "" Then
    StrSignature = GetBoiler(sPath)
Else
    StrSignature = ""
End If

With itm
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & StrSignature
End With  

Set itm = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.readall
ts.Close
End Function
```